# My puts function is not working in 16-bit code

Tags: gcc, x86, bootloader, 16-bit, real-mode

I'm writing a bootloader using *GCC* and a small assembler bootstrap routine. I've written a `puts` routine that prints a string to the display using BIOS interrupts that doesn't appear to write strings properly.

My bootstrap assembler file `boot.s` contains:

```
.code16 .section .text

.extern main
.globl start
start:

    mov     $0x7c0,     %ax
    mov     %ax,        %ds
    mov     %ax,        %es
    mov     %ax,        %fs
    mov     %ax,        %gs

    jmp     main

here:
    hlt
    jmp here
```

My *C* code in `main.c` is:

```
/*
 * A 16 bit bootloader.
 */

void putchar_bios(unsigned char ch);
void set_videomode(unsigned short mode);
void puts(char str[]);

#define set_stack(ss, size)                                     \
{                                                               \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (                                      \
            "mov     %%ax,      %%ss\n"                         \
            "mov     $512,      %%sp\n" : : "a" (ss), "r" (size)\
        );                                                      \
}

#define set_videomode(mode)                                     \
{                                                               \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (                                      \
            "int $0x10\n" : : "a" (mode)                        \
        );                                                      \
}

void putchar_bios(unsigned char ch)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "int $0x10\n" : : "a" (0x0E | ch)
        );
}

void puts(char *str)
{
    while(*str)
        putchar_bios(*str++);
}

void main()
{
    set_stack(0x07C0, 512);
    set_videomode(0x03);

    char name[] = "0001234567890";
    puts(name);

    //This works fine.
    //  for(i=0; i<15; i++)
    //      putchar_bios(name[i]);
    while(1);
}
```

I have successfully done this entirely in assembly, but now I'm trying to migrate it to *GCC* . I am using a cross-compiler (i386-gcc) and used `-m16` flag also. I have used a custom linker script.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary");
ENTRY(start);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00) {
        *(.text);
    }
    .data : SUBALIGN(0) {
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata);
    }
    .bss : SUBALIGN(4) {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(.COMMON);
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __bss_end = .;
    }
    __bss_sizel = SIZEOF(.bss)>>2;
    __bss_sizeb = SIZEOF(.bss);

    /* Boot signature */
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE) {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}
```

The script I used to compile, link and run in *QEMU* are:

```
i386-elf-gcc -m16 -static -ffreestanding -nostdlib -c boot/boot.s
i386-elf-gcc -m16 -static -ffreestanding -nostdlib -c boot/main.c
i386-elf-ld -T link.ld -o b.bin -nostdlib --nmagic boot.o main.o
dd if=b.bin of=HD.img conv=notrunc
#add some noticable garbage to second sector since I also try to read it next
echo "This is the second sector..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................." | dd seek=512 bs=1 of=HD.img

qemu-system-i386 -hda HD.img # -boot a -s -S
```

Why does my program not display strings via my `puts` function properly?

Comment: Any chance it's clashing with a compiler built-in named 'puts', i.e. does it work if you rename it to something else? There's also int 0x10 ah=0x13 you could use instead to print the string in one go.

Comment: No names doesn't clash as I ma using a cross compiler and it has no such function [No standard library at all.]. And I will be self-reliant (without using BIOS) so I didn't use the BIOS functions

Comment: OK. It's not clear from the docs that `-nostdlib` automatically implies `-fno-builtin`.

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing with _GCC_ and the way it does 16-bit code I discourage the use of `-m16`. GCC's code will run inreal mode but it will generate 32-bit instructions that will only run in emulators or real hardware that support 386. The code generated will notwork on 8088/8086/8186/80286. On a side note I recently wrote a small trivial bootloader with a similar linker script for someone in an IRC chat. It contains everything in the _C_ file. That small project can be found here: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/ircasm/gccboot

Comment: That example also uses the regparm(3) calling convention to pass first 3 parameters in registers rather than the stack. The code is also intended to be compiled with optimizations on.

Comment: `set_stack(0x07C0, 512);` will become an issue since the top of stack will grow down from 0x07c0:0x200 (Physical address 0x07e00). This is actually at the top of your bootloader and could easily interfere with code and data as you bootloader expands. Maybe consider `set_stack(0x0000, 0x7c00);` this will start the top of stack at physical address 0x07c00 just below the bootloader itself.

Comment: And if you don't already know:To convert a segment:offset pair to a physical address you shift the segment left 4 bits (same as multiply by 16) and add the offset. So 0x07c0:0x200 would be a physical address  of (0x7c0<<4)+0x200 = 0x7e00.

Comment: One other observation `"int $0x10\n" : : "a" (0x0E | ch)` . You take the `ch` and bitwise OR it with 0x0E. This seems wrong. I think you were going for something like `"int $0x10\n" : : "a" ((0x0E << 8)| ch)`. This would shift 0x0E left 8 bits and then place ch in the lower 8 bits. AX would then have AH=0x0E and AL=ch. As well Int 0x10/Ah=0x0e takes a page number as in an input parameter in _BH_. Without setting it to 0 the output may not go to the display. See: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm

Comment: set_videomode has a potential bug. _GCC_ knows nothing about DOS interrupts. Int 0x10/ah=00h will clobber the _AX_ register. You have only defined an input operand. This means you are telling _GCC_ that _AX_ will not be altered, when in it fact is. this can lead to subtle bugs. The compiler may assume the value in AX remains constant and generate code. You'll have to tell the compiler that _AX_ will be overwritten. You can use a dummy variable as output for _AX_ and also  use _AX_ as an input.

Comment: Rather than using C macros for some of the functions, create regular functions but define the functions as `static inline`. This also improves type checking. Compile you bootloader for size optimizations (`-Os` on the GCC command line).

Comment: If you haven't realized it yet, inline assembler is fraught with pitfalls unless you know exactly what you are doing. If you are new to GCC extended assmebler templates it is often better to avoid them and place assembler functionality in a separate assembly file. This will be less space efficient and less optimizable but it would likely lead to fewer bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I set the values of segment registers to some garbage (0x7c0) which caused this to happen. I modified my assembly file to zero out the segment registers. The code now looks like:

```
.code16
.section .text

.extern main
.globl start
start:

    xor     %ax,        %ax
    mov     %ax,        %ds
    mov     %ax,        %es
    mov     %ax,        %fs
    mov     %ax,        %gs

    jmp     main

here:
    hlt
    jmp here
```

I had expected that the compiler would automatically initialize the segment registers, but it was not.